# Number of ways to partition a sum with a restriction

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I want to find the number of ways to express a given integer N as a sum of M integers with each term of the sum restricted to being smaller or equal than a given integer k. Is there a closed expression for this? I can express it as an integral of a generating function but cannot find a closed expression.

Comment: @MattiP.  In a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), the order of the summands does not matter.  They are usually written in descending order of size so that no partitions are missed.

Comment: The number of partitions of $N$ into integers not exceeding $k$ (with no restriction on the number of summands) equals the number of partitions of $N$ into $k$ parts (with no restriction on the size of the parts). There are closed form formulas for small values of $k$ but no general closed form. Restricting both the size and number of parts I suspect has similar limitations on the existence of closed forms.

Comment: This paper by Euler may be helpful: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505425.

Also, check out this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656079/coefficient-of-xi-in-xx2-xkn#comment7517645_3656079