# Calculating Coefficents of a single variable polynomial

Tags: probability, polynomials, generating-functions, roots-of-unity, multinomial-coefficients

Given:
$$ 
(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^k)^n 
$$

Is there a formula to calculate the coefficient of $x^a$ (where $a$ can be any integer value less than $k^n$) that's more efficient than grinding through every possible permutation that sums to $a$ with the multinomial theorem and then summing them all?

Comment: Check the article in the first comment at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656079/coefficient-of-xi-in-xx2-xkn?noredirect=1

Comment: @Macavity Thank you.

Comment: @Macavity It's hard to get a better answer than Euler has a paper on it. :)